# images drag drop ios like happn app

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uipangesturerecognizer

i am working on a functionality of image arrangement for that i want to let user select multiple images to its account like for example a user added 5 picture. then the images will show like a big picture for the album cover and remaining pictures on the side one under another in small sizes.

this is not a big deal and can be done by using scrollview and image view. but after that i want to do is to change my main big image with any of the remaining small images by long select the image and drag to the main big image and the small image get large to cover the big image space and the big image get small to get back to the small image place.

[image: sample image] 
how should i suppose to do this. Kindly guide

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, you can do that by create 2 subviews `UIImageView` and `UICollectionView`. Long select `UICollectionCellView` will update `UIImage` in `UIImageView` and `UICollectionCellView`.

Comment: thanks for the response.... yeah thats a good idea.... but according to me is not -> long select UICollectionCellView will update UIImage thats good but it will not look real untill we drag an image to uiimageview and then small dragged image will expand and take the space...

Comment: i have an another idea, what if i use pan gesture on the UICollectionView cell and then drag the cell toward the center of image view and then detect its cordinate  and do the fade in out animation accordingly